# 405 Method Not Allowed when creating a contact form on PHP

Tags: php, html, css

When I try to submit i get the [405 Method Not Allowed](http://prntscr.com/j0rcgn) error.

I am hosting from AWS and my domain is on GCP.
This is my index.html file

```
 <div class="w3-col m6">
            <form action="#"  action="contact-form.php" method ="post" target="_blank">
                <div class="w3-row-padding contact-form"  style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
                    <div class="w3-half">
                        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name ="name" placeholder="Name" required name="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-half">
                        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Email" name = "email" required name="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <textarea class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message" name= "message" required name="Message"></textarea>
                <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-section w3-right" type="submit" name="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-send-o" style="font-size:24px"></i> SEND
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my contact-from PHP file

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "xxx@gmail.com"; // my emails Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // sender's Email address
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";       
    $message = $name . " " . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];           
    $headers = "From:" . $from;        
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);    
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    header("Location: index.php");

}
```

Comment: Are you on Amazon S3?

Comment: you have 2 `action=''` remove one `<form action="#"`

Comment: Remove your first action="#". You have two different actions here

Comment: Not sure, but may this be the answer you're looking for? [Amazon S3 - 405 Method Not allowed using POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32036032/6597672)

Comment: I have removed the empty action function. Yes I am on Amazon S3. I will look at the link above thanks.